# print in a specfic location TCL

Tags: tcl

Is there any way to print argument in a specific location?
I tried to use the below command but each argument depend on the previous one.

`puts [format "%0s%20s%30s%40s" $check $runtime $cpus $result]`

That's mean if $check is long name all the other data will be shift accordingly.
Is there any way to determine the specific location to puts the var?

Comment: You may need to `exec tput ...`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't indicate how you would like to resolve the situation when a string is too long to fit the allotted space. Assuming you want to cut off the tail of the string, you can specify a maximum length:

```
puts [format %-10.9s%-10.9s%-10.9s%-10.9s $check $runtime $cpus $result]
```

The - will anchor the strings to the left, 10 specifies the field width and 9 limits the number of characters printed.

Demo:

```
set check "longcheckname"
set runtime "forever"
set cpus "all"
set result "passed"
puts [format %-10.9s%-10.9s%-10.9s%-10.9s $check $runtime $cpus $result]
```

Result:

`longcheck forever   all       passed`